# Regular Expression For Numbers, Letters and :

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for specific strings:
Each string to be matched should start from the digit [1-9] and may or may not contain prefixes.

For example:

```
0  - not match
1  - match
9  - match 
2: - not match
3:ABC - match
4:56ARD20 - match
5:56ARD20(any other chars except [0-9A-Z]) - not match

A:5GTS - not match (just a digits in the first part)
A1:GRT - not match (just a digits in the first part)

:FDE3  - not match (first part should contain only digits)
:      - not match (empty first digital part)
```

So the first part of the string -> is only digits (mandatory).
String may contain one symbol (:) with [0-9A-Z] suffix.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, cool. You've told us what you're trying to do. Do you have a question? _Specifically_, what have you tried? How did it fail to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: I have tried this: ^[a-zA-Z0-9:]*$ but it's fail sorry.

Comment: And how is it failing? What should it match that it isn't matching, or what should it _not_ match that it _is_ matching? Ideally we'd like you to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not very strong in regular expressions. That's why I'm here.

Comment: You still need to clearly explain what the problem is with your regex. _Again_, _specifically_, how is your regular expression not working as expected? What should it match that it isn't matching, or what should it _not_ match that it _is_ matching? And _again_, please read [ask] and review the documentation for [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex  `^[1-9]\d*(?::[A-Z\d]+)?$`

Readable

```
 ^                    # BOS
 [1-9] \d*            # Digit(s) required (can only start with 1-9
 (?:                  # Optional group
      :                    # Colon
      [A-Z\d]+             # Upper case letters or digits
 )?
 $                    # EOS
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next code

```
<?php

        $regExp = "/^[1-9][0-9]*(:[0-9A-Z]+)?$/";
        $test = array("0", "1", "2:", "3:ABC", "5:56ARD20*", "A1:GRT", " ", ":FDE3" , ":" );
        foreach( $test as $val) {
                echo "$val",  "  -> " , preg_match($regExp, $val), "\n";
        }


?>
```

Small improvement: "number" should start with [1-9], after that 0 is allowed.